# How can I show the player's cards in the form of arrays in the playing cards written in C programming?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, enums, typedef

**Hello** to everyone. I am currently writing a card code in C program. But I can't handle some problems :( The name of the game is Bastra (or Pishti). What I need is to put 4 cards face up on the table and divide 4 cards to 4 players. When we run the code, this happens, but what I need is **to define the players' cards as an array.** Cards are written randomly on the screen, but I cannot use it in the next steps because it is not an array. One such part I need is for example `Card board_cards [3];` , `Card player_1_cards [3];` , `Card player_2_cards [3];` and so on. I think I need to do this at the display part but I have no idea how to do this. I would be glad if you help me :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 9
#define MAX_CARDS 52
#define MAX_RANKS 13
#define MAX_SUITS 4
#define Empty NULL
//structure definition
struct card { 
    char *rank;    
    char suit[MAX];  
} ;

typedef struct card Card;
enum name {Spades, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts};
enum number {Ace, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King};
char * suits[] = {"Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
char * ranks[] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

void initialize(Card []);
void shuffle(Card []);
void display(const Card[]);

void cleaning_player_card(int player, int card_index, Card player_deck[3],Card the_card);
void cleaning_board(int board_card_index, Card board_deck[], Card board_card);
int arr1 ,arr2,arr3, arr4;
int main(void)
{
    Card deck[MAX_CARDS] = {""};
    initialize(deck);

    printf("BOARD:\n");
    shuffle(deck);
    display(deck);

    printf("\nPlayer one ... \n");
    shuffle(deck);
    display(deck);

    printf("\nPlayer two  ... \n");
    shuffle(deck);
    display(deck);

    printf("\nPlayer three  ... \n");
    shuffle(deck);
    display(deck);

    printf("\nPlayer four  ... \n");
    shuffle(deck);
    display(deck);
    return 0;
}

/*
  initialize the deck of cards to string values
*/

void initialize(Card deck[]){
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CARDS; i++){
        deck[i].rank = ranks[i%MAX_RANKS];               
        strncpy(deck[i].suit, suits[i/MAX_RANKS], MAX);  
}
}

void shuffle(Card deck[]){
    int card_p = 0; //index of card 
    int i = 0; //counter
    Card temp = {" "}; //temp holding place for card
    srand(time(NULL)); //seed the random numbers with current time
    for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        card_p = rand() % 52; 
        temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[card_p];
        deck[card_p] = temp;
    } 

}

void display(const Card deck[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      const char *ranks[]={deck[i].rank};
      const char *suits[]={deck[i].suit};
        printf("%s of ", *ranks);
        printf("%s", *suits);
        
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a two-dimensional array such as cards[MAX_CARDS][MAX_SUITS].

Answer (score 0):

I've studied your code but there are some places I don't understand.
And then I ran your code.
I saw more than one player owning a card.

For example;

```
BOARD:
Six of Spades    
Seven of Spades
Eight of Spades   
Three of Spades

Player one ...
King of Spades
Jack of Clubs
Seven of Clubs  1
Eight of Spades   

Player two  ...
Nine of Diamonds
Two of Diamonds
Four of Diamonds  2
Seven of Clubs    1

Player three  ...
Six of Diamonds
Five of Spades
Six of Hearts   3
Four of Diamonds  2

Player four  ...
Nine of Clubs
Four of Hearts
Ace of Hearts
Six of Hearts  3
```

And I decided to rearrange the code.

Code is --->

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
/*
We will store data in memory in the form of a char variable.

For example;
        MEMORY      PRINT
        0-1         Spades of Two
        3-10        Hearts of Jack
        2-12        Diamonds of King
        1-0         Clubs of Ace

*/
    
typedef struct{
    char name;
    char value;
}card;


/*
transformer function -->
converts the data in memory to STRINGS that we can understand. 
And then it prints on the screen.
*/

void transformer(card elements){ 
    const char *namee[4]={"Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts"};
    const char *valuee[13]={"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    char var_name[10],var_value[10];
    strcpy(var_name,namee[elements.name]);
    strcpy(var_value,valuee[elements.value]);
    printf("%s of %s\n",var_name,var_value);
}

void print_1d_arr( card *arr, int arr_size){
    for (int i=0;i<arr_size;++i){
        transformer(arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_2d_arr( card **arr, int arr_x, int arr_y){
    for (int i=0;i<arr_x;++i){
        printf("PLAYER %d\n",i+1);
        print_1d_arr(arr[i],arr_y);
    }
}

card *make_1d_arr( int arr_size){
    card *son=(card *)malloc( sizeof(card)*arr_size );
    return son;
}

card **make_2d_arr( int arr_x, int arr_y){
    card **son=(card **)malloc( sizeof(card*)*arr_x );
    for (int i=0;i<arr_x;++i){
        son[i]=(card *)malloc( sizeof(card)*arr_y );
    }
    return son;
}

/*
in_arr function -->
This function checks whether the data we are looking for is in the list(ARRAY).
Returns 1 if present, 0 otherwise.
*/

int in_arr(card *arr, card elements, int size_arr){
    for (int i=0;i<size_arr;++i){
        if (arr[i].name==elements.name && arr[i].value==elements.value){
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
mix function --->
This function will mix all the cards.
And It will give us a list of mixed cards.
*/

card *mix(){
    card *son,var_forever;
    son=make_1d_arr(52);
    char var_name, var_value, count_size;
    count_size=0;
    while (1){
        if (count_size==52){
            return son;
        }
        var_name=rand()%4;
        var_value=rand()%13;
        var_forever.name=var_name;
        var_forever.value=var_value;
        if (in_arr(son,var_forever,count_size)){
            continue;
        }
        son[count_size]=var_forever;
        ++count_size;
    }
}

/*
player_arr function --->
This function will give us the cards that players have.
For example;
        MEMORY              PRINT
        [ [ 1-1 , 3-10 ]        PLAYER 1
          [ 2-0, 0-5 ] ]        Clubs of Two
                                Hearts of Jack
    
                                PLAYER 2
                                Diamonds of Ace
                                Spades of Six

Note;This function does not have print function.

x--->

Imagine our mixed deck like this:
    0-1 , 3-10 , 2-5 , 1-5 , 3-3 , 2-11 ,........., 2-4 , 3-3 
    For example, two people play the game 
    And let's distribute 3 cards to each player.
    Cards to be given to the first player=0-1 , 3-10 , 2-5 
    Cards to be given to the second player = 1-5 , 3-3 , 2-11

If you know Python, this function is as follows in Python
Python Code;

def playe_arr(number_of_players, TNOCEPH):
    all_deck = mix()
    total_cards = number_of_players*TNOCEPH
    son=[]
    if total_cards>52:
        print("ERROR ---> the total number of cards is greater than 52")
        return
    a=0
    b=TNOCEPH
    for i in range(number_of_players):
        player_variable=all_deck[a:b]
        son.append(player_variable)
        a+=TNOCEPH
        b+=TNOCEPH
    return son
*/

card **player_arr(int number_of_players, int TNOCEPH){ // NOCEP == the number of cards each player has
    srand(time(NULL));
    card *all_deck=mix();
    int total_cards=number_of_players*TNOCEPH; //number of cards to be distributed
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    card **son=make_2d_arr(number_of_players,TNOCEPH);
    if (total_cards>52){
        printf("ERROR --->the total number of cards is greater than 52\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<total_cards;++i){ //Please look up (x)
        if (y==TNOCEPH){
            y=0;
            ++x;
        }
        son[x][y]=all_deck[i];
        ++y;
    }
    return son;
}

/*
finish function --->
Combine all functions.
*/

void finish(){
    int NOP, TNOCEPH;
    printf("Number of players = ");scanf("%d",&NOP);
    printf("The number of cards each player has = ");scanf("%d",&TNOCEPH);
    card **son=player_arr(NOP,TNOCEPH);
    print_2d_arr(son,NOP,TNOCEPH);
}

int main(){
    finish();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it works for you. Kolay gelsin ;)